# How to add .png images to pdf using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I try to draw png images using pdfBox, the pages remain blank. Is there any way to insert png images using pdfBox?

```
public void createPDFFromImage( String inputFile, String image, String outputFile ) 
        throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try
    {
        doc = PDDocument.load( inputFile );

        //we will add the image to the first page.
        PDPage page = (PDPage)doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get( 0 );

        PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
        if( image.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpg" ) )
        {
            ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream( image ) );
        }
        else if (image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tif") || image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tiff"))
        {
            ximage = new PDCcitt(doc, new RandomAccessFile(new File(image),"r"));
        }
        else
        {
            BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( image ) );
            ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);
  //          throw new IOException( "Image type not supported:" + image );
        }
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);
        contentStream.drawImage( ximage, 20, 20 );
        contentStream.close();
        doc.save( outputFile );
    }
    finally
    {
        if( doc != null )
        {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You showed us code. But what is the issue?

Comment: when i tried to draw png images pages remain blank that's my question is there any way to insert png images using pdfBox...

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the upcoming 1.8.5 version, see http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2030 . It is already fixed in the 2.0 version (which has a different API), see http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1990 . You can get both from svn.

Comment: @user3404729 i have to sincerely thank you for this code

Comment: what is the issue here doe?

Comment: I was not able to add even a .jpg file, This is the ecxeption I got: 2020-01-30 15:03:14,536 ERROR [at.home.digest.web.ExposeBean] (default task-4) Error creating Expose PDF file : javax.imageio.IIOException: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50
        at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:731)
        at java.desktop/com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly

Answer (score 6):

There is a pretty nice utility class [PDImageXObject](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.7/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html) to load Images from a java.io.File.
As far as I know, it works well with jpg and png files.

```
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFileByContent(imageFile, doc);
contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 20f, 20f);
```