# PDFBox v2 write PNG image to PDF file, getting empty file

Tags: java, image, pdf, png, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox 2. Trying to write a PNG image file to new PDF file.

I saw there was already an answer that mention it was fixed on PDFBox2:
[How to add .png images to pdf using Apache PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317706/how-to-add-png-images-to-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox) and 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1990

This is my code:

```
package pdfProj;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.LosslessFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject;

public class b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PDDocument doc = null;
        doc = new PDDocument();        
        doc.addPage(new PDPage());
        try{
            BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( "c://temp//line_chart.png" ) );
            PDImageXObject  pdImageXObject = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, awtImage);
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, new PDPage(), true, false);
            contentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, 200, 300, awtImage.getWidth() / 2, awtImage.getHeight() / 2);
                contentStream.close();
                doc.save( "c://temp//pdf//PDF_image.pdf" );
            doc.close();
        } catch (Exception io){
            System.out.println(" -- fail --" + io);
        }

    }
}
```

There is no exception. Just getting an empty PDF file created.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is that you add a new page to the document

```
doc.addPage(new PDPage());
```

but then create a content stream for yet another new page which you don't add to the document:

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, new PDPage(), true, false);
```

You should create the content stream for the page you added to the document, e.g. like this:

```
PDDocument doc = null;
doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);
try{
    BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( "c://temp//line_chart.png" ) );
    PDImageXObject  pdImageXObject = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(doc, awtImage);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, false);
    contentStream.drawImage(pdImageXObject, 200, 300, awtImage.getWidth() / 2, awtImage.getHeight() / 2);
    contentStream.close();
    doc.save( "c://temp//pdf//PDF_image.pdf" );
    doc.close();
} catch (Exception io){
    System.out.println(" -- fail --" + io);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error.  -- fail --javax.imageio.IIOException: Unsupported Image Type

Comment: @Dhrumil that would indicate that the type of image you use is not supported by the java image io classes, at least not without additional plugins.

Comment: I am getting this error for any type of images. like JPG,JPEG,PNG etc.. i am  getting same error with Apache PDFBox 2.0.5.. i have to moved to lower version of PDFBox and this issue is not coming. i am not sure why this issue is coming to new version.

Comment: Please make that a stack overflow question in its own right and supply both your exact pivotal code and sample files to reproduce the issue.

Comment: When i used older version of PDF box i am able to generate image in PDF. I am not sure what is the issue with latest version. i will post this issue to apache PDF issue tracker.